# Send image from Android Studio to Python

Tags: python, android

I have some problems in my projects.
I send byte array from Android client to Python server and in Python server, I want to change byte array to Bitmap image file using PIL.Image.frombytes() but it occurs some error.
I can't handle this error. How I can handle it?
Bitmap from Android size is 640x480

```
public void request(){
        handler = new Handler();

        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        final byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
        Log.d("log1", Integer.toString(byteArray.length));

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("log1", "Start Thread to connect");
                String newIP = "localhost";
                int port = 5001;

                try {
                    socket = new Socket(newIP, port);
                    Log.d("log1", "Correct Connect");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("log1", "Not Connect");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    dos.write(byteArray);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Buffer", "Incorrect Buffer");
                }
```

This is my Android code to send bytearray to python server
In Log.d("log1", Integer.toString(byteArray.length));, result's length is same in python server received.
But To use PIL change byte array into Bitmap, there is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/junso/PycharmProjects/Exercise/server2.py", line 39, in <module>
    image = Image.frombytes('L', (width, height), bytes(data))
  File "C:\Users\junso\PycharmProjects\Exercise\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2615, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "C:\Users\junso\PycharmProjects\Exercise\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 800, in frombytes
    raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328198/pil-valueerror-not-enough-image-data

Comment: You better save the jpg file bytes in the byte array directly to file. Then you have all times to inspect the jpg file.

Comment: @Leogout Thank you, I solve this error by your comments!!! Thank you!!!